# Get single digits from a larger number

Tags: c#, algorithm, int

I have a question and I don't seem to get it right, is there a way to get single numbers from a larger one written on a textbox?
For example, I enter the number `123456789` in a textbox and I want to get all of those digits contained on that large number on 9 different, let's say ints, like this:

```
int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;
int thirdNumber;
int fourthNumber;
int fifthNumber;
int sixNumber;
int seventhNumber;
int eighthNumber;
int ninethNumber;
```

is there a TextBox property to do it or do I have to write the algorithm for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through each character of the TextBox string and input it into an `int` array. Using an array is a much better approach than using individual variables.

```
string text = "123456789"; //Set to TextBox text
int[] numbers = new int[text.Length]; //Create array of ints
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    //Parse each character to an integer
    numbers[i] = Int32.Parse(text[i].ToString());
}
```

You may want to look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm) array tutorial and loops if you are unfamiliar.

With this code, you can now retrieve each number with:

```
int firstNumber = numbers[0];
int secondNumber = numbers[1];
etc, etc
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something like that but since I'm a little rusty in terms of array and loops, it was taking me more time than it should. I'll give it a read to that tutorial. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "123456789"; 

var nums = 
(from i in input
select int.Parse(i.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: You can always print numbers with `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, nums));`

Comment: @AD.Net I retracted my vote, but you may want to add some additional information. OP does not seem familiar with arrays and may not know how this code works or how to access each element in `nums`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wasn't looking for the actual code since I always try to figure these things out by myself, but this was taking me too much time. I'm a bit worn out in terms of arrays, but this was a really helpful reminder. I can't vote up since I don't have enough reputation, but I really appreciate the help from you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Well...a `TextBox` contains *text*: it has a `Text` property that returns a string representing the text box's content. C# strings are `IEnumerable<char>`: it should be pretty trivial to enumerate the characters in the string. Given `char c`, you can get its integer value as a decimal digit by evaluating `c-'0'`. If the result is within the domain 0—10, you've got a decimal digit.

You could say something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> TextDigits( this TextBox instance )
{
  foreach( char c in instance.Text )
  {
    int d = c - '0' ;'
    if ( d >= 0 && d <= 9 ) yield return value ;
  }
}
```

Or something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> TextDigits( this TextBox instance )
{
  int value = int.Parse(instance.Text) ;
  if ( value == 0 ) { yield return 0 ; }
  while ( value != 0 )
  {
    int d = value % 10 ;
    value /= 10 ;
    yield return d ;
  }
}
```

Or you could say something like

```
TextBox tb ;
int[] digits = tb
               .Select( c => c - '0' )
               .Where( c => c >= 0 && c <= 9 )
               .ToArray()
               ;
```

There is...as they say...more than 1 way to get there from here.

Comment: Thanks! the second one seems more suitable for what I need. I appreciate the time you took to, not only answer my question, but also to give me three ways to do what I need. Thank you! And sorry if the question was too obvious, is the price I pay for being a newbie.